# Is there anyway to know if user stopped loading a page?

Tags: jquery

I want to know if it's possible to know if a user has let a page to load or he has clicked the X from Chrome or Firefox to stop it perfoce.

I have this code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
if (condition == 1){
...
else
...
```

If user let to load the website until the end, first condition will comply.

If user forces to stop the loading, second condition will comply.

Comment: if a user stops the loading clickg the X from firefox or chrome, he'll not get a "prize", to call it some way..., if he lets the page loading until the end, he'll get the "prize". with my code, i've checked to force stopping the loading, and i can get the mini prize, when i must only get it if i let the page loading til the end

Comment: if user doesn't load all the way, the window load event shouldn't fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user clicked X then that means most likely he didn't load the jQuery library, or your code...

If you want check if the page is fully loaded then there is a trick that might help...

Put a div at the end of the page and bind the events to it when it's ready

```
jQuery('.div-trick').load(function () {});
```

Edit: more over you can place your jQuery code at the end of the page...

Note : don't forget don't wrap your code with document ready because then it wont be fired...

Edit : hmm, I guess my ultimate solution is to do this ...

```
function loadchecker() {
    if($('.div-trick').length<0){
        alert('page is not fully loaded');
    } else {
        alert('now the page is loaded')
    }
}

// fast counter is an over kill but it wills stop when the page is loaded
var checker = window.setInterval(loadchecker, 5);

//then on my documnet ready i will            
$(function(){
     clearInterval(checker);
});
```

Pretty dirty solution but what can i say this is all what can be done as far as i know...

As for your last comment, why do you want to check if he didn't load the page ! all you need to do is check if the page is loaded and give him the prize

```
$(function(){
    // page is fully loaded
    // you will get the prize

});
```

or bind the ajax call on the load of the image or the add that you want... as shown above...

Comment: the problem is that i use jquery and then send data using ajax to a php file which will store something to the database, then if a user is "inteligent", he can stop the loading just in one moment, and he'll get a mini prize, to call it some way.., and the good way should be that he gets that "mini prize" if the page is completely loaded without interferences, thanks for edit now i'll check it

Comment: you should have said it like that at first place ..!!! all you need is to wrap the ajax call with a document ready function , cuz  why do you even check for the opposed ... just think about it this way if the document is loaded then i will give you the prize ... and do this `$(function(){// give him the prize}) `

Comment: @frankie4 now you are assuming user doesn't cause abort of your ajax. Seems like too many unknowns create a 100% solution

Comment: @charlietfl +1 i knew that it's doing to end up this way ... cuz why does any body wana see if some one has canceled his page ..

Comment: as yuor answer has been the most explained, i give you the +1, but i've looked for other code, and $(window).load(function(){ works for me, anyway thank you very much!

Comment: glad it helped at least ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") { 
   // Loaded
} else {
   // Not loaded
}
```

Or just use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   // Loaded
}
```

Comment: i'll try first, but what's the difference between jQuery(window).load(function () and $(document).ready( function() {

Comment: The ready event occurs after the HTML doc has been loaded; whilst the load event is triggered when the page (including graphics) is fully loaded. You want to capture the moment when the HTML document load is cancelled

Comment: first option doesn't work for me, and second doesn't wait to load the page, it appears automatically when page is opened